# Extracting the values from an IGroupedObservable

Tags: f#, system.reactive

Reactive.Linq's `GroupBy` leaves you with an `IObservable<IGroupedObservable<'TKey, 'TValue>>`. How do you get the values from the IGroupedObservable? The key is accessible by `x.Key`, so I suppose the values could be projected by some transformation of sorts.

This is roughly what I want to do:

```
open System.Reactive.Linq

let doStuffWithEvenNumbers i = i*10
let doStuffWithOddNumbers i = i*3

let numbers = Observable.Range(0, 10)
let groups = numbers.GroupBy(fun i -> i % 2 = 0)

let subscription1 = groups.Where(fun i -> i.Key).Subscribe(doStuffWithEvenNumbers)
let subscription2 = groups.Where(fun i -> not i.Key).Subscribe(doStuffWithOddNumbers)
```

Of course, the two `let subscriptionX =` lines won't compile, since I need to get from `IGroupedObservable<bool, int>` to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IGroupedObservable<'TKey, 'TValue>` extends `IObservable<'TValue>`, that's how you get to the values. In your case you can do that in many ways:

```
// you can use SelectMany to 'flatten' the observable
groups.Where(fun i -> i.Key).SelectMany(fun o -> o :> IObservable<int>).Subscribe(doStuffWithEvenNumbers)
```

Note that Subscribe call take an `Action`, whereas in your case you defined the method as a `Func`. You need to remove its returned value for the call to work.

Comment: `SelectMany(id)` was my first attempt, but I get the error `No overloads match for method 'SelectMany'`. Same result if I copy+paste your line verbatim.

Comment: Updated the answer, you need to upcast the `IGroupedObservable` to an `IObservable` (not implicit in F#), also beware your subscriber methods need to be changed, e.g. `let doStuffWithEvenNumbers i = printf "%i" i*10`